# Ruby on Rails and Heroku "App Crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash

I've gone through MANY forum posts about this exact problem and I have not found a solution.

**App works locally but not on Heroku.**

http://majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com/

*What am I missing??!!*

**Heroku Logs:**

```
    searoth@searoth-VB:~/Desktop/rails_projects/MajorLeagueBetting$ heroku logs
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2013-04-01T20:14:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:14:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-01T20:14:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-01T20:24:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-01T20:24:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 34898`
2013-04-01T20:24:48+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T20:24:48+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T20:24:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Head2headBet(Table doesn't exist):Class (NameError)
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:12:in `<class:Head2headBet>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-01T20:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-01T20:34:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-01T20:35:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 15944`
2013-04-01T20:35:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for mo
re on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T20:35:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:12:in `<class:Head2headBet>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Head2headBet(Table doesn't exist):Class (NameError)
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T20:35:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T20:35:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-01T20:35:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Here is the gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'railties', '3.2.13'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.0'
gem "colorbox-rails", "~> 0.0.7"
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'tabletastic'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have forgotten to migrate

heroku run rake db:migrate

the clue is in

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Head2headBet(Table doesn't exist):Class (NameError)
```

2013-04-01T20:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:12:in `'

Comment: Okay I have done the db:migrate before but it is still crashed.

HEROKU LOGS:

2013-04-01T22:25:37+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2013-04-01T22:25:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631617 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Using `$ heroku pg:psql -a majorleaguebetting`, can you confirm the `Head2headBet` table exists?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the state of your database you may try any of the following commands

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:reset # WARNING DESTRUCTIVE
heroku run rake db:setup # WARNING DESTRUCTIVE
```

as John Baynon said, the clue is in `table doesnt exist` line

Comment: Okay I have done the db:migrate before but it is still crashed.

HEROKU LOGS:

2013-04-01T22:25:37+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631617 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: That was just a general error, can you edit your post to include a full trace?