# Ruby on Rails Heroku app crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash

My app works locally but not the Heroku website.

I have searched and tried many other posts regarding this situation.

http://majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com/

Before changing database to pg I was using SQLite3

**Heroku Logs**

```
 2013-04-01T22:19:23+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by coryr32@gmail.com
2013-04-01T22:19:25+00:00 heroku[run.4531]: Awaiting client
2013-04-01T22:19:25+00:00 heroku[run.4531]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-04-01T22:19:26+00:00 heroku[run.4531]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-01T22:19:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-01T22:19:34+00:00 heroku[run.4531]: Process exited with status 0
2013-04-01T22:19:34+00:00 heroku[run.4531]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-01T22:19:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 14899`
2013-04-01T22:19:39+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T22:19:39+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Head2headBet(Table doesn't exist):Class (NameError)
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:12:in `<class:Head2headBet>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/head2head_bet.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-04-01T22:19:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-01T22:19:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-01T22:19:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-01T22:19:58+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:19:59+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631278 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:20:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:24:27+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:reset` by coryr32@gmail.com
2013-04-01T22:24:30+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: Awaiting client
2013-04-01T22:24:30+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:reset`
2013-04-01T22:24:30+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-01T22:24:44+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-04-01T22:24:45+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: Process exited with status 0
2013-04-01T22:24:45+00:00 heroku[run.9491]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-01T22:25:06+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by coryr32@gmail.com
2013-04-01T22:25:11+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: Awaiting client
2013-04-01T22:25:11+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
2013-04-01T22:25:11+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-01T22:25:29+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-04-01T22:25:31+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: Process exited with status 0
2013-04-01T22:25:31+00:00 heroku[run.2856]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-01T22:25:37+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631617 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:40+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:40+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631619 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:25:41+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:26:01+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:26:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/puq5so.com?g=49501E2D-56F4-42FB-B15E-C774D06A7D24&s=5FA810DC-7AF7-11E2-97F6-12313B082201&z=2631641 host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-01T22:26:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=majorleaguebetting.herokuapp.com fwd="173.16.26.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'railties', '3.2.13'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.0'
gem "colorbox-rails", "~> 0.0.7"
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'tabletastic'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: as an aside: you have the postgres gem listed in two places

Comment: it looks like you have a reference to current_user, but this variable does not exist in your context. Typically this variable is defined using a gem like devise used for authentication

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, but he says it works in dev.

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the config/database.yml ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails and Heroku "App Crashed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751705/ruby-on-rails-and-heroku-app-crashed)

Answer (score 0):

Try starting from scratch on creating the database:

```
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, do you think it has anything to do with config/database.yml file?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're referencing `current_user` where it is not defined.

Also - As someone who has utilized Heroku in the past, I would highly recommend going with a hosted VPS setup like Linode if you're the type of developer that likes complete control of your setup. We had lots of slow support issues as well as much higher bills while using Heroku and switched to Linode and never looked back.

You might also might want to consider Amazon AWS as their prices keep coming down.

Just my 2 cents as someone who has been there before.

One last thought - because you're using PG now, be aware that it treats Booleans differently than other DB's ("true" instead of 1). See here: [Comparison of database column types in MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite? (Cross-Mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942586/comparison-of-database-column-types-in-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite-cross-map)