# Error while deploying Rails application to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku, but there seems to be some issues. Every time that I try:

```
git push heroku master
```

my heroku logs tell me that my app crashed and that I'm missing the 'debugger' gem. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395453/gem-install-debugger-error) thread here and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#debugger-gems-fail-to-install) page on Heroku. When I try to install the 'byebug' gem, bundle tells me that it won't install on Ruby 1.9.3, and when I follow the advice from Heroku and put the 'debugger' gem in the development group in the Gemfile I still get the same error.

I've also updated my bin/rails, bin/rake and bin/bundle files according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751705/ruby-on-rails-and-heroku-app-crashed) thread, but to no avail.

My heroku logs:

```
2015-09-13T13:49:23.849824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-09-13T13:49:23.863155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-13T14:04:45.333599+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-13T14:04:45.333617+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-13T14:04:45.274914+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 96bfb3a by lj_nissen@gmx.de
2015-09-13T14:04:45.275022+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by lj_nissen@gmx.de
2015-09-13T14:04:46.116335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-13T14:04:53.209874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16268 -e production`
2015-09-13T14:04:59.039827+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346436+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346441+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:16268
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346443+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346444+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346445+00:00 app[web.1]: You're missing the 'debugger' gem. Add it to your Gemfile, bundle, and try again.
2015-09-13T14:04:59.346490+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-09-13T14:05:00.403110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-13T14:05:00.404488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-13T14:05:00.389462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-09-13T14:05:07.914037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3507 -e production`
2015-09-13T14:05:14.080304+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276459+00:00 app[web.1]: You're missing the 'debugger' gem. Add it to your Gemfile, bundle, and try again.
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276512+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276457+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276456+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276455+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3507
2015-09-13T14:05:14.276452+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-09-13T14:05:15.122910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-13T14:05:15.107610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'shopeng', '0.0.1', :path => './vendor/shopeng' 

#gem "shopeng", :git => "git@github.com:ljnissen/shop_engine.git"

gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
#gem 'less'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.13'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Recor
gem 'pg' 

# Use SCSS for stylesheets


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'rmagick'

#gem 'linecache19', '0.5.12'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

#Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

My Ruby version is 1.9.3-p551

Rails 4.0.13

and I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can show your Gemfile?

Comment: I've tried to run the 'debugger' gem in production. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should `bundle install` before redeploying to Heroku.